# Converting Column headings into Row data

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a table in an Access Database that has columns that I would like to convert to be Row data.

I found a code in here

[converting database columns into associated row data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714353/converting-database-columns-into-associated-row-data)

I am new to VBA and I just don't know how to use this code.

I have attached some sample data

How the table currently is set up it is 14 columns long.

```
+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| ID    |  Name  |  2019-10-31 |  2019-11-30 |  2019-12-31 |  ... etc ...   |
+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| 555   |  Fred  |          1  |          4  |         12  |                |
| 556   |  Barney|          5  |          33 |         24  |                |
| 557   |  Betty |          4  |          11 |         76  |                |
+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+

I would like the output to be

+-------+------------+-------------+
| ID    |  Date      |  HOLB       |
+-------+------------+-------------+
| 555   |  2019-10-31|  1          |
| 555   |  2019-11-30|  4          |
| 555   |  2019-12-31|  12         |
| 556   |  2019-10-31|  5          |
| 556   |  2019-11-30|  33         |
| 556   |  2019-12-31|  24         | 
+-------+--------+-------------+---+
```

How can I modify this code into a Module and call the module in a query?

Or any other idea you may have.

Comment: Well that doesn't look like what I typed in for the table and what I am looking for

Comment: The code found is perfectly valid, but it is _SQL_ (for a query), not VBA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting database columns into associated row data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714353/converting-database-columns-into-associated-row-data)

Comment: Hi Gustav I kind of understand it but still do not.  I am still learning most of this.  Ultimately I would like to use the VBA code in that example I just don't know how to update it to work.

Comment: Start getting the SQL to work for at least some of your columns. The VBA only creates this SQL dynamically. Adjusting this is futile as long as you don't have ready the SQL to create.

Comment: Hi Gustav,  I am getting a syntax error from clause notice when I use the SQL.  this is what I have SELECT a.* INTO NewTable FROM TBL_Part_Loan_HighBal
  SELECT [ID], "2019-10-31" As Date, 2019-10-31 As DateVal FROM TBL_Part_Loan_HighBal
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [ID], "2019-11-30" As Date, 2019-11-30 As DateVal FROM TBL_Part_Loan_HighBal;      I'm sure I am missing something but just don't see it